# Coincidence Topologies for $L^p$ spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, integration, lebesgue-measure

If $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces then it is well-known that the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$ coincides with the *topology of uniform convergence on compacts*.  Therefore, the latter is generated by the "convenient" sub-basic sets
$$
\{f: f(K)\subseteq O\} \, K\subseteq X \mbox{ compact},\, O\subseteq Y \mbox{ open} .
$$

Is there a similar coincidental, "topologically flavoured"/natural topology on the local $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^D)$ spaces.

Comment: First a remark.  The compactness and metric conditions at the beginning are irrelevant.  This holds for any topological spaces $X$and $Y$.  The natural topology on the local $L^p$-space is the one generated by the seminorms $$ p_K(f)=(\int_K ||f(t)||^p dt)^{1/p}  $$ as $K$ ranges over the compacta. We are using any of the usual norms on the range space.

Comment: The second point I do know, but I'm mostly looking for a more topological (not metric-thoeretic) "coincidental-type" of description...